# Notation for Transformation Law for Connection Coefficients

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, riemannian-geometry

Can someone clarify the following notation for me? From Lee's "Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds", proposition $4.7$:

> Let $\nabla$ be a connection in $TM$. Suppose we are given two smooth local frames $(E_i)$ and $(\tilde{E_j})$ for $TM$ on an open subset $U \subset M$, related by $\tilde{E_j}=A^j_i E_j$ for some matrix of functions $(A^j_i)$. Let $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ and $\tilde{\Gamma}{^k_{ij}}$ denote the connection coefficients of $\nabla$ with respect to these two frames. Then $$\tilde{\Gamma}{^k_{ij}} = (A^{-1})^k_p A^q_i A^r_j \Gamma^p_{qr} + (A^{-1})^k_p A^q_j E_q (A^p_j).$$

Are we summing like $$\sum_{q,p,r}\bigg((A^{-1})^k_p A^q_i A^r_j \Gamma^p_{qr}+(A^{-1})^k_p A^q_j E_q (A^p_j)\bigg)$$ or like
$$\sum_{q,p,r}\bigg((A^{-1})^k_p A^q_i A^r_j \Gamma^p_{qr}\bigg)+\sum_{p,q}\bigg((A^{-1})^k_p A^q_j E_q (A^p_j)\bigg)?$$ What's the vector $E_q$ doing in a real valued function?

Comment: Have you tried to do the calculation yourself?

Comment: What is the definition of a tangent vector?

Comment: I hadn't tried because I wanted to be able to work backwards, but I got it now. We're summing twice and $E_q$ acts on $A^p_j$, thought of as a real function, not as a constant like the rest. Thank you